# how to modify url in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, url-rewriting

I want to change my url from

```
http://mghworld.net/mgh_qa/zend_modules/public/showcase/hoteldetails/index/city/Dharamshala/type/3-Star-Hotel/guesthouse/Surya-Resorts_1715.html
```

to

```
http://mghworld.net/mgh_qa/zend_modules/public/showcase/hoteldetails/index/Dharamshala/3-Star-Hotel/Surya-Resorts_1715.html
```

Comment: I want to change my url from http://mghworld.net/mgh_qa/zend_modules/public/showcase/hoteldetails/index/city/Dharamshala/type/3-Star-Hotel/guesthouse/Surya-Resorts_1715.html to http://mghworld.net/mgh_qa/zend_modules/public/showcase/hoteldetails/index/Dharamshala/3-Star-Hotel/Surya-Resorts_1715.html in zend framework

Comment: Short and concise question, [short and concise answer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html).